# Replace default DNS name resolution in Java

Tags: java, jvm, dns, tcp

I'd like to change the way the JVM resolves domain names in HttpURLConnections.

Instead of going to DNS servers through the default TCP/IP stack I wanted to write my own code to resolve domain names.

Is there a way to replace the default name resolution mechanism?

Comment: DNS replaces hostnames with IP address, the simplest thing to do is to replace the hostnames with IP addresses yourself.

Answer (score 2):

i have no idea if it would work, but there are system properties

System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", localhost);
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");

perhaps if you have your java application open a port on the dns port (53) and process requests yourself.

Of course this falls down if there is a dns server already on the current machine.

Answer (score 2):

Construct URLs replacing the hostname with the numeric IP address and then add the `Host` header manually to the `HttpUrlConnection`.

```
http://www.myserver.com/foo.html
```

Is equivalent to

```
http://192.168.1.100/foo.html
Host: www.myserver.com
```

[dnsjava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/) gives you more control in resolving DNS names over the standard Java APIs.