# Java - InetAddress.getByName fails but cmd ping works, why?

Tags: java

Using an internal computer name in `InetAddress.getByName( String )` is failing for me.  However if I use the same string in a command window after "ping", it works just fine.

Also, the InetAdress method works fine if I use an external name, such as "www.google.com", or if I use the actual IP of the internal host.

It's throwing an UnkownHostException.

- `InetAddress.getByName( "computername.company.ca" )` - UnkownHostException
- `InetAddress.getByName( "computername" )` - UnkownHostException
- `InetAddress.getByName( "1.2.3.4" )` - Works!
- `InetAddress.getByName( "www.google.com" )` - Works!
- `ping computername.company.ca` - Works!
- `ping computername` - Works!
- `ping 1.2.3.4` - Works!

Why can't InetAdress use the computer name to resolve the address?

Comment: `is failing for me` - expand it

Comment: @JigarJoshi - I did. Keep reading.

Comment: It means the name resolution mechanism used by the JVM is not the same as the system's one...

Comment: have you configured java network setting differently ?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284063/replace-default-dns-name-resolution-in-java) <-- do you have any JVM property of those `sun.xxx` in your running JVM?